# Laravel Collection - multiple where conditions

Tags: php, laravel, collections

Is there a way to pass multiple where conditions into the Laravel's collection? I mean something like:

```
$filters = [['col1', '=', 'val1'], ['col2', '=', 'val2']];
$found = $collection->where($filters)->first();
```

I know it works with the eloquent query builder, but not quite with the collections. I know I can chain multiple `->where` statements (even within the foreach loop) but I need to have the original collection object, and cloning it works, but isn't so fast.

```
$localCollectionObject = $localCollection->first(function ($value, $key) use ($remoteCollectionObject, $compareColumnNames)  {
    foreach ($compareColumnNames as $compareColumnName) {
        if ($value->{$compareColumnName} != $remoteCollectionObject[$compareColumnName]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

This works fine also, but is even slower than `clone $localCollection`.

Or maybe I can "reset" where statements somehow?

I'm searching it within foreach loop with different conditions and that's a problem.

Comment: what does 'clone' have to do with filtering anything ever?

Comment: It's all within the foreach loop, with different conditions, so I need to search in original collection, without `where`.

Answer (score 6):

You can always use your own closure with filter:

```
$collection->filter(function ($item) {
   return $item->col1 == 'val1' && $item->col2 == 'val2';
});
```

Comment: As you can see I've tried it (first in this case works the same as filter) and it's slower than clone ;)

Comment: I guess I don't understand your problem then...  Of course it's slower than clone, clone isn't having to compare anything.  Is your problem that you just want to stop the filter after the first element is found?

Comment: I'm just asking if there is something faster than clone.

Comment: But clone just creates a duplicate object, it doesn't filter...  so why would you compare the two?

Comment: I suggest you clear up your question because the title and first statement don't seem to match what you're actually after.